# How do you use more than 9 regex capture groups in emacs?

Tags: emacs, regex

I'm trying to transform a rather long sequence of values to a different format, using emacs' replace-regex command. There are more than 9 values to extract, so the \1 - \9 back references are not enough.

How can I back reference more than 9 capture groups in emacs?
Can named groups be used? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Emacs 23, you can include Lisp code in a [regexp replacement text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html). This gives you a way of using more backreferences. The function [`match-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html#index-match_002dstring-3049) returns the numbered backreferences.

```
\1 … \9 \,(or (match-string 10) "")
```

Since Emacs 22, if there's any parenthesized group in the regexp that you don't need to have a backreference for, use `\(?:…\)` (Emacs calls this a [shy group](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#index-shy-group_002c-in-regexp-683)).